# How to insert paging in stored procedure using SQL reporting services

Tags: sql, sql-server, service, reporting-services, reporting

I have a report query that has many records and is getting very slow because the report brings all the results and then do the paging in memory.
It would be possible to perform paging dynamically? For him to bring only the first 'n' records and only after the user access the next page of the report he go to the bank and bring the next page.

Comment: You can try to use the page number as a parameter in reporting-services, [All] / Page Number. But you are limited to the Reporting services functionalities. For example implement a dropdown box with the number of pages and have the procedure do the paging. And group your Matrix/table per page.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with native SSRS paging.  You could simulate it by using an action to call the same report with a set of paging parameters, but it'd be a lot of work to subvert the way SSRS usually works.  And it wouldn't work with exporting/printing.  Printing/exporting the report would only get the initial page, not all pages.

A better way might be to limit the amount of data that can be returned in a single report, by forcing a limited date-range or other logical restriction.